# PHP keeping track of how many online rooms exist

Tags: php, online

I'm making an online card game project but now I have a minor issue:

In my game there are rooms that users can join. How do I find out how many created rooms there are?  I thought about using a static counter but it didn't work. (I thing that the reason it didn't work is because every process is run on a separated thread so using static keyword wont help me solve this problem.)  Also I thought about saving it to the database but than when someone cancels a room, for others, it wont be visible.

Do you know any solution how to do this?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on this comment, "Also I thought about saving it to the database but then when someone cancels a room, for others, it wont be visible."  What do you mean?

Comment: When you send request to server it returns you room list. But when you  get room list if someone destroy room you wont be able to see it because your list wont be updated.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a handful of rooms, I'd use a flat file, otherwise you'll need to post some code of what you tried using a database...  This should be a very simple request.

Here's a flat file solution.  Save this as a file on your server and call it with `?do=add` or `?do=sub` to add or subtract the count respectively.  If you don't specify `do` then it will print the current number-

```
<?php
if($_GET['do']=="add"){
    $new = intval(@file_get_contents("count.txt"))+1;
    $fp = fopen("count.txt", "w");
    fwrite($fp, $new);
    fclose($fp);
}else
if($_GET['do']=="sub"{
    $new = intval(@file_get_contents("count.txt"))-1;
    if($new < 0){$new = 0;}
    $fp = fopen("count.txt", "w");
    fwrite($fp, $new);
    fclose($fp);
    }else{
    print @file_get_contents("count.txt");
}

?>
```

Comment: Yea I get that but what if you want to join room you send request for online rooms and server sends you back list. Meanwhile someone cancel that room or some other people join that room you wouldn't have idea about that.

Comment: Not sure what you're saying here...  Instead of just recording a count, are you wanting to have a list of active rooms and then have the script to automatically count the number of active rooms?  You can do this with a list of uniqueids loaded into an array.

Comment: My room is a class and every time someone creates room it instance new class. How can other users have information about class that some other user instanced ?
May be that is better formed question.